# What material are these cabinet doors made of?

Tags: wood, cabinets, plywood

Our home has cabinets that look like this. I was wondering if anyone recognizes the material this is? I'm assuming it's some hardwood plywood but I don't recognize the wood species.

[image: Picture of a cabinet]
[image: view from bottom]

Comment: Open one of the doors and show us what the bottom edge looks like.

Comment: If it were a plastic "shrink-wrap" laminate then I'd expect the grain pattern to continue around the bottom edge in the same direction, but it does not. So it's likely a thin hardwood veneer over particle board or MDF. No idea what species of hardwood the veneer might be though.

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you trying to match the finish? Maybe add another cabinet?

Comment: Identifying wood species from pictures is hard enough that it's off-topic over at [woodworking.se]. Odds are really good, though, that for a flat panel cabinet door like that, it's nothing more than a picture of wood printed onto a plastic veneer. The pic of the bottom, which shows face grain, not end grain proves it. If you're trying to get new cabinets that match, simply eyeball it at the store.

Comment: @FreeMan "The pic of the bottom, which shows face grain, not end grain"  That end view can also be edgebanding. The faces can still be wood veneer.

Comment: Utterly standard mid-century flatpack furniture technique - the core is banded so it's hidden. The only unbanded edges are those that don't show when assembled. Between inheritance and yard sales, I have a bunch of the stuff.

Comment: Kinda looks like just veneer to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is rift-sawn white oak, in a slip-matched veneer design:
[image: rifth white oak]
https://oakwoodveneer.com/oak-veneer-white-rift.html
[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS952US952&sxsrf=AJOqlzXRokMvuZjRi4k6mz9dL6sPtUye_w:1678370433675&q=rift%20white%20oak&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7rICMgc_9AhXVF1kFHdZCDTcQ0pQJegQICxAB&biw=984&bih=843&dpr=0.9)

Probably clear-coated with lacquer, if it is not a formica or melamine plastic surface. (I lean towards real wood veneer, since the doors are different enough grain pattern.)

Comment: I saw this wood out the wazoo in my last ten years' work in a cabinet shop in New Jersey USA. Was all the rage with the designers.

Comment: Excellent. I agree it has a lacquer. I matched the maple shelves very closely with arm-r-seal so guessing they used the same finish on both.

Comment: I found this plywood at the local hardwood store in Seattle. Looks like a perfect match and is indeed rift sawn oak. Very likely this is where the cabinet maker got it.
https://imgur.com/a/wsfcOA1

Comment: Yep, that looks like the stuff! We had hundreds of sheets of that come through our cabinet shop over the years.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like standard "Danish Modern" or "Mid-Century Modern" teak veneer, which is actual wood veneer over an MDF (medium density fiberboard) core.

[image: Teak veneer image from jsowoodproducts.com]

Often goes along with flatpack assembly methods (camlocks and dowels) - *i.e.* what most people now think of as "Ikea" assembly, before Ikea.

It was very common for the late 1940's to at least the 1960's

Comment: My thought as well. Almost certainly MDF of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hardwood.

It is laminate over particle board.

Comment: Can you tell what kind of laminate?

Comment: "there is no wood with that kind of grain" actually that is rift-sawn white oak. It's veneer, slip matched, i think they call it.